# Angular 2: Enable button when form is updated

Tags: for-loop, button, edit, angular2-forms

I want to enable a button if at least one field in the form is updated, but when I input some changes in my textarea, the button remains disabled.

I have 3 items in my form - Input Field, Multiple Select Dropdown, Textarea

The button enables when there are changes in the input field or multiple select dropdown, but when I change something in the textarea, it won't enable. Maybe there's something wrong with the `for loop` and the `breaks`

Here are my codes:

```js
if (this.data.process == "update") {
  for(const f in this.categoryForm.value){
      console.log(this.categoryForm.value);
      if (f == "categorytags"){
          let categorytagsArray = [];
          let categorytagsFormArray = this.categoryForm.value[f];

          for (const x in this.data.category[f]) {
              categorytagsArray.push(this.data.category[f][x]._id);
          }

          if (categorytagsArray.length != categorytagsFormArray.length) {
              this.disableButton = false;
              break;
          } else {
              for (const i in categorytagsFormArray) {
                  if (categorytagsArray.indexOf(categorytagsFormArray[i]) == -1) {
                      this.disableButton = false;

                      break;
                  } else {
                      this.disableButton = true;
                  }
              }
          }
          break;
      } 
       else {
          if (this.categoryForm.value[f] == this.data.category[f]) {
              this.disableButton = true;
          } else {
              this.disableButton = false;
              break;
          }
      }
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="dialog-form">
    <div class="header">{{data.title}}</div>
    <div class="content">
         <form class="ui form" [formGroup]="categoryForm" *ngIf="categoryForm" novalidate>
            <div class="field required" [class.error]="formErrors.name">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Enter Name..." maxlength="100">
                <div *ngIf="formErrors.name" class="field-error">
                    {{ formErrors.name }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required" [class.error]="formErrors.categorytags">
                <label>Category Tag</label>
                <select name="categorytags" id="categorytags" class="ui fluid dropdown" formControlName="categorytags" multiple="">
                    <option [attr.value]=categoryTag._id *ngFor="let categoryTag of categorytags">{{ categoryTag.name }}</option>
                </select>
                <div *ngIf="formErrors.categorytags" class="field-error">
                    {{ formErrors.categorytags }}
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="field">
                <label>Remarks</label>
                <textarea rows="6" formControlName="remark" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
            </div> 
        </form> 
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <button class="ui basic button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        <button class="ui primary button" [disabled]="disableButton" (click)="save()">{{data.process.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + data.process.slice(1)}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just use `[disabled]="categoryForm.pristine"`?

Comment: The problem with the .pristine booleans, is that once they change, they do not go back, even if you undo all the changes you introduced. @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Yeah, I know. In my case, I don't really care about that. I estimate that in a hundred edits, that generates maybe a couple of unnecessary save events, but I prefer that over the additional complexity and performance impact of comparing the form value with the original value.